# Power Bi: Populate a parameter used in source query from url

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power Bi, I have looked many videos and read many community posts, stack overflow posts, documentation papers.
I have not found yet a method to what I have in mind and need.
I must create a report in Power Bi and embed it in our web application, that will show a dashboard with fashion order statistics. 
All data come from a database on Azure.
All data sources are created from a query.
There is the fact table (orders) and 4 dimensions. Dimensions are related to "orders" fact table by id.

This is how "ORDINI" (orders data) is created:

[The fact table (ORDINI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W48Fu.png)

This is then linked for example to "TIPOLOGIE_VENDITA" through tipologie_vendita.id --> oridini.id_tipologia_vendita in Power Bi:

[A dimension table (TIPOLOGIE_VENDITA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD8wz.png)

I would like to call this report with a JS call and pass the parameter called "language", that will filter the source "TIPOLOGIE_VENDITA" on "id_lingua" field. I do not want to do a filtering on the dataset already loaded, using a parameter or through a filter/slicer.
I want to filter **directly** the data coming from database **AT RUNTIME**, limiting the date inside the report. I must add other parameter used in the same way, so for me it is very important to know how to do this.

Is it possible?
How can I get this or a similar solution if not?

Thank you all, Marco

Comment: If you will "filter directly the data coming from the database", this means that you are using Direct Query and then in this case the filters will be propagated to the database and will not "post-filter" the data after it's loaded. So simply use filters when embedding the report.

Comment: So, are you saying that as I have done is already correct? Does it means that I cannot filter data with a parameter from js call using "standard" import data with query using refresh button (at the moment the data are preloaded, I am not using direct query)? Do I have to create the parameter "language" inside power bi desktop or simply pass it through js when calling the report?

Comment: If you imported the data in your model, setting a parameter and refreshing it will affect **all** users viewing the report, i.e. it is not possible two users to see different languages at the same time. In addition, refreshing a dataset takes considerable amount of time. Simply use filters, regardless of the storage mode.